# Completion of localization of completion

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, localization, completion

Let $(A,m)$ be a noetherian local ring, 
and let $p \subseteq A$ be a prime ideal.

From this data, we can construct two rings:
1. We may localize $A$ at $p$, and then complete,
obtaining the $pA_p$-adic completion of $A_p$.

2. We may complete $A$ at $m$, 
   then localize $\hat{A}$ at $p\hat{A}$,
   and then take the adic completion of $\hat{A}_{p\hat{A}}$ at 
   $p\hat{A} \cdot \hat{A}_{p\hat{A}}$.

My question: are these two rings isomorphic?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  No, those are not the same.  Consider the case when $A$ is the localization of $k[t]$ at the maximal ideal generated by $t$ and where $p$ is the zero ideal.  Then $A_p$ is the fraction field $k(t)$, which also equals the $pA_p$-adic completion of $A_p$.  However, the completion of $\widehat{A}$ at the image ideal equals the Laurent series field $k((t))$.